# How To Create Toggle Yes/No Category Attribute?

Tags: category-attribute, magento2.4.6

I want to create Yes/No flag attribute in category admin panel.

Data patch is already created and in category_form.xml i am trying different solutions.

````
<fieldset name="general">
        <field name="enable_slider">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Slider</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
</fieldset>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code to complete my requirement and it's working fine.

```
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="enable_slider">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Slider</item>
                <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<fieldset>
    <field name="enable_slider" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/single-checkbox-toggle-notice" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Enable Slider</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Source: [Adobe DevDocs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/components/checkbox-toggle-notice/)